# How do i redirect a php login file back to index.html presented with a message 'Welcome User'

Tags: php, html

My work codes but the message is not showing up after clicking login. It does redirect for 5 second but does not show the appropriate message 'Welcome User'

```
$error = "";
$success = "";

//  username: user password: pass
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['pass'];
  if ($username == "user") {
    if ($password == "pass") {
      $error = "";
      $success = "Welcome user!";
      header('Location: index.php');
      sleep(5);
    }
    else {
      $error = "Wrong Password!";
      $success = "";
    }
  }
  else {
      $error = "Wrong Username!";
      $success = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: `header("Location: index.php?message=$message");` then use `$_GET` to display message

Comment: you could either use session to store your messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use session variables to store the message and display it one time, then delete it.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = 'Success! Operation completed';
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
```

Then in `index.php`, display the message

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    print_r($_SESSION['message']);#display message
    unset($_SESSION['message']); #remove it from session array, so it doesn't get displayed twice
}
```

Comment: i mean when he uses a seperate file to process the login

Comment: Thank you! Now how do i set a cookie to save the user's login state. If the cookie states the user is logged in, the login form should not display. If the cookie does not state the user is logged in, the login form should display.

Comment: @IloveCorgis you just answered your own question. If user exists, set `$_COOKIE['login'] = true`, then check on every page for that. Then when user logs out, kill the cookie by setting the time-span to a time of the past.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Session` variables if you don't want to pass the message via URL.

Comment: Mind how OP can do that?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile we could use a variable like $_SESSION['status'] to store the messages and then we could display the content in different pages. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you guys mind showing the code if i were to implement it to my code.

Comment: @MrIseeyu2 instead of using error and success just use one session variable to store status and then show the content of the session variable after redirection.

Comment: @suvojit_007 Thank you so much! Now how do i set a cookie to save the user's login state. If the cookie states the user is logged in, the login form should not display. If the cookie does not state the user is logged in, the login form should display.

Comment: @IloveCorgis [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486177/set-a-cookie-to-save-login-details-php). You could use session variables also like just store the user id and check whether this variable is set or not. Just put this code at the top of your login script. If the user id is set, then just redirect to the user page otherwise give the login script.